# How to fix link between onedrive folder and sharepoint document library after URL change?

Tags: windows-7, onedrive

I have some sharepoint document libraries linked to my home via onedrive for business. Now due to administrative measures the URLs of the doc libs have changed and onedrive fails to sync the folders.

I could delete the folders and sync the doc libs from scratch but I will loose all locally done changes to all files.

Can I just manipulate some registry entries to get the URLs fixed?